# Server 2008 R2 repair install

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, drivers, drac

Is it possible to do a repair install on a server 2008 R2 Enterprise machine like we used to be able to do on 2003? I need to reinstall on a remote server and don't have a driver cd in the drive just a copy of server. I am worried that when it comes back up I won't have any drivers for the NIC. I have a iDRAC but can't seem to send files over the DRAC to the machine. Sadly this server doesn't have an SD card in the DRAC with the files I need. I welcome any suggestions if the repair is not possible. Our IDC is in Chicago and they are buried under snow so I won't be able to get another admin on site until at least tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I had to do a repair on 2008 (not R2) earlier last year. The option of repair is there. I had some bootloader issues (a badly scoped script was deleting NTLDR) that repair managed to fix up.

Comment: Thanks! This is a production terminal server and I didn't want to start moving users until I was sure I could do this. The issues we are seeing are only affecting certain printers, so we have only been moving users as needed (there are still 25+ on there).

Comment: Why are you repairing the OS for a printer problem? Why do you have to move users, are you not using roaming profiles?

Comment: Our ERP vendor suggested against it @joeqwerty. We have tried everything short of a reinstall to fix the printer issues. We use Tricerat Simplify console so its a shared SQL database that controls our users desktops an printers on our term servers. None of the other terminal servers are having issues so it must be something that is wrong specifically with that server.

Comment: OK, but it sounds like you're rebuilding the entire engine because the transmission slips.

Answer (score 1):

Kyle, guess this answer's is late,  listing steps on how to get OS / any media from a client (say desktop / laptop) available remotely on Dell servers with the iDRAC in them..as the steps below have worked..

As your Dell Server has iDRAC, you could launch the iDRAC's IP address in your Internet Explorer to get the iDRAC user interface.. Once there, launch the Virtual Console screen and use its menu option(File -> Launch Virtual Media) to launch the Virtual Media screen where all your Optical / USB/ Floppy drives would be listed.

Pop in the OS disc at your client machine and check if the same is listed in the open Virtual Media screen. If yes, all you got to do is check the box next to the entry where it shows your OS disc and it instantly maps this content on to the remote Dell server which can be seen in the Virtual Console screen.